# Как в шаблоне Joomla вывести свой модуль?

Tags: php, joomla

Вообщем пишу я свой шаблон для Joomla 3 и тут мне понадобилось вывести свой модуль, в нем простенький `html` код, в папке с шаблоном я создал папочку `html` и в ней папку `mod_mymod` и уже в ней файл `default.php` в котором и находится мой код. Как теперь этот модуль вывести в самом шаблоне?

Пробовал писать вот так.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mymod"/>
```

Но модуль не выводится, как его вывести? Помогите разобраться ребята.

Comment: Что, никто ничего неподскажет?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо еще добавить ваш модуль (mod_mymod) в модулях с названием mymod, и не забыть выставить там позицию и страницы отображения.

Answer (score -1):

Добавь в файл `templateDetails.xml` строчку `<position>mymod</position>`